# clear previous css settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollbar

i am working on responsive web-design. I have written jQuery plugin, part of which add smart_scrollbar claass to two divs when view-port >786, followed by add perfectScrollbar() http://www.yuiazu.net/perfect-scrollbar/  to smart_scrollbar and remove class when view port is <786. My issue class does remove on view-port <786 but it functionality still remains there. I need to clear somehow this jquery behavior.

```
$(window).bind('load resize', function () {

var viewport_width = $(window).width()

   if (viewport_width > 768) {


            //***************Add Scrollbar to panels***************//

           $(".Functions_Panel_Wrapper").addClass("smart_scrollbar")

           $(".Function_Page_Wrapper").addClass("smart_scrollbar")

           $(".smart_scrollbar").perfectScrollbar();


        }
        else if (viewport_width < 768) {

            //***************Remove Scrollbar From panels***************//

            if ($(".Functions_Panel_Wrapper").hasClass("smart_scrollbar") )
            {

                $(".Functions_Panel_Wrapper").removeClass("smart_scrollbar")


            }

            if ($(".Function_Page_Wrapper").hasClass("smart_scrollbar"))
            {

                $(".Function_Page_Wrapper").removeClass("smart_scrollbar")
            }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [**GitHub documentation**](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar), you can use this to remove the scroll bars:

```
$(".smart_scrollbar").perfectScrollbar('destroy');
```

So you could try this:

```
$(window).bind('load resize', function () {
    var viewport_width = $(window).width()
    if (viewport_width > 768) {
        //***************Add Scrollbar to panels***************//
        $(".Functions_Panel_Wrapper").addClass("smart_scrollbar")
        $(".Function_Page_Wrapper").addClass("smart_scrollbar")
        $(".smart_scrollbar").perfectScrollbar();
    } else if (viewport_width < 768) {
        //***************Remove Scrollbar From panels***************//
        if ($(".Functions_Panel_Wrapper").hasClass("smart_scrollbar")) {
            $(".Functions_Panel_Wrapper").removeClass("smart_scrollbar")
        }
        if ($(".Function_Page_Wrapper").hasClass("smart_scrollbar")) {
            $(".Function_Page_Wrapper").removeClass("smart_scrollbar")
        }
        $(".smart_scrollbar").perfectScrollbar('destroy');
    }
}
```

Comment: i am using .perfectScrollbar('destroy')inside viewport_width if <786 as it wont add smart_scollbar class to divs on first instance if it open it mobile... so don't need to destroy which isn't created!